# Calculating true distance of cost distance raster using ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst, cost-path, cost-surface, least-cost

I have calculated cost distance using a raster unrelated to path distance (a heat index) but would like to also measure the true path distance of those 'routes.' Is there a way to calculate such? If I simply calculate path distance, the tool obviously takes different paths than that used for cost distance. I'm using ArcMap.

Comment: Convert backlink raster to flow direction using Int(Pow(2,blink-1)) and use flow length from hydrology toolset.

Comment: @FelixIP This worked. Thank you!

Comment: Please post workflow as answer to your own question. It's ok to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took @FelixIP's suggestion and converted the backlink raster (from the cost distance tool) to flow direction using the formula **Int(Power(2,"backlink"-1))** in raster calculator. I then used the flow direction raster as input for the flow length tool. This created a raster of true distance values corresponding to my cost distance raster.